# Remove a node without knowing the parent (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Can I remove a `Node` from a scene-graph without knowing its parent?

In others words, can I do something like this?

```
@FXML private ToolBar toolBar;

@FXML
protected void handleCloseButtonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    toolBar.getParent().getChildrenUnmodifiable().remove(toolBar);

    actionEvent.consume();
}
```

If I do this, it throws a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the [UnsupportedOperationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html), because [`Parent#getChildrenUnmodifiable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getChildrenUnmodifiable--) returns a read-only list:

> Gets the list of children of this Parent as a read-only list.

It's always better and safer if you store the reference of the parent container, but theoretically you can do it by (down)casting the `Parent` object returned by the `getParent()` method to the type of the parent container.

For example if the `ToolBar` is added to a `VBox`:

```
((VBox) toolBar.getParent()).getChildren().remove(toolBar);
```

Or, if you want to be a little bit more generic, you can cast the returned parent to a [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) after type check, as this class is the super class of JavaFX containers which allows modification on the children list:

```
if (toolBar.getParent() instanceof Pane)   
    ((Pane) toolBar.getParent()).getChildren().remove(toolBar);
```

Still, I would suggest to store the reference of the parent container instead of following one of these (or similar) approaches as this is not a clean, and because of the downcasting not a safe solution (without type check).

Comment: I never had the case when I had to look for the parent of a particular element of a UI tree, the sub-components were designed always in a way to avoid this. I hope we can agree, that designs like that are better :) I updated the second part again to emphasize that the check has to be done for both (was clear to me but the answer was misleading, you are right). Which solution is "better": to keep a reference or to cast - I cannot tell (for me one seems so for you other). Maybe the answer together with these comments will help others with this problem in the future(that's SO's goal, isn't it?:))

Comment: argg ... the parent that exposes its children as a modifiable list is Pane (not Region) - my fault, sorry. Removed my comments, as I agree with you in that such a requirement shouldn't arise in half-way sane ui designs :) At least not in fx, as it doesn't provide any general public api for a node to remove itself from its parents - that's (most probably, cant be sure, obviously) a conscious decision, so users should play along ...